# powershell pipe to array returns as character array

Tags: arrays, powershell, character, unique

I am trying to build an array with the results of the following powershell script. I would then like to only output the unique results in that array (I am expecting duplicates). I tried but it does not work. One thing I noticed is that my array is being converted to a character array. So if I call a single object in the array ($array[1]) it only displays one character, which may be why the select -unique is not working.

Please help.

```
$servers="Server1","server2"
$regex="(\.\d\d\d.*\()"
$path = "SomePath"
$yesterday = (get-date).Date.AddDays(-1)
Foreach ($server in $servers) {Get-ChildItem -Path $path -recurse | where { $_.LastWriteTime -le $yesterday } | ForEach-Object { Get-Content -Path "$_" -TotalCount 2 | select-string $regex | % { $_.Matches } | % { $array += $_.Value.Substring(5,6) } }}
$array|select -Unique
```

Comment: What is initial value of `$array`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you initialize the `$array` value as an array, then your code will work.  Without this knowledge, PowerShell is treating `$array +=` like concatenating strings together.

```
$array = @()
$servers="Server1","server2"
$regex="(\.\d\d\d.*\()"
$path = "SomePath"
$yesterday = (get-date).Date.AddDays(-1)
Foreach ($server in $servers) {Get-ChildItem -Path $path -recurse | where { $_.LastWriteTime -le $yesterday } | ForEach-Object { Get-Content -Path "$_" -TotalCount 2 | select-string $regex | % { $_.Matches } | % { $array += $_.Value.Substring(5,6) } }}
$array|select -Unique
```